# Setting up Text editor like Vim,Spacemacs to work with docker containers without installing tools on the host machine

Tags: bash, macos, vim, docker, spacemacs

I am trying to set up a modular development environment with docker containers,
In which:

1) no sdks/dev tools/compilers getting installed in my host machine (those should live inside the specific containers only)

2) Using my text editors (Vim, Spacemacs) in their GUI version on OSX

The main problem here is that most of the time the text editors specific language plugins (like [elm layer](https://github.com/syl20bnr/spacemacs/tree/master/layers/%2Blang/elm) in Spacemacs) needs those tools in order to work correctly.

Any help?

Comment: It sounds like you want two mutually excluding things.

Comment: While romainl's answer doesn't seem very helpful, he may be right, unless there is a way you can point your text editors at the various docker containers, you won't be able to use their features fully

Comment: the text editor can use docker run command in order to run specific tool the problem here that it will be extremely difficult to change each plugin implementation to use docker run command

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the end what worked for me was setting global alias.sh file sourcing it in my .bash_profile with the following commands:

```
  grep -q -F 'source ~/.docker-shared/alias.sh' ~/.bash_profile \
    || echo 'source ~/.docker-shared/alias.sh' >> ~/.bash_profile
```

and

```
  mkdir -p ~/.docker-shared && touch ~/.docker-shared/alias.sh
```

Then for each development environment I can create alias.sh file containing all commands from the container using docker-compose:

```
  alias elm-repl='docker-compose run web elm-repl'
```

When my docker-compose.yml contians the following:

```
 version: "2"
 services:
   web:
     build: .
     image: web
       ports: 
         - "8000:8000"
       volumes: 
         - .:/app
         - ~/.docker-shared:/shared
       entrypoint: ""
       command: bash -c "mkdir -p /shared && cp /app/alias.sh /shared"
```

running

```
 docker-compose up web
```

will setup my environment and aliases. Those aliases will be used in the text editors.

In my case I had to set vimrc and spacemacs to use a interactive shell for that to work, so I added the following lines to my config files:

.vimrc:

```
  set shellcmdflag=-ic
```

.spacemacs:

```
 (setq shell-command-switch "-ic")
```

Here's my [elm dev environment](https://github.com/countoren/elm/tree/master)